# Type 'Observable<Todo[]>' is missing properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working through a YT tutorial and I've gotten stuck as I can't see where the error is coming from?

Error Message : Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'Todo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.ts(2740)

```
export class ToDosComponent implements OnInit {

  todos:Todo[];

  constructor(private todoService:TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todos = this.todoService.getTodos();

  }
```

This is the class it refers to

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Todo } from '../models/Todo';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {
  todosUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
  todosLimit = '?_limit=5';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getTodos():Observable<Todo[]>{

    return this.http.get<Todo[]>('${this.todosUrl} $ {this.todosLimit}');

  }
```

Comment: Well you said `this.todos` should be an array of `Todo`s, then assigned an *`Observable`* of an array of `Todo`s to it instead. The compiler's telling you the right thing; that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to `getTodos()` function and assign the value `this.todos` inside it. Try the following

```js
export class ToDosComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];

  constructor(private todoService:TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe(
      response => { this.todos = response },
      error => {
        // always good practice to handle error from HTTP observables
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Angular HttpClient's `get()` method returns an observable. So when you assign it to `this.todos` you'd be wrongfully assigning the observable to it instead of the response from the HTTP request. To access it, you need to subscribe to the observable.